# How to convert from one coordinate system to other?

Tags: android, windows, opengl, glm-math

I've developed an application for windows (it uses coordinate system, where `Y` increases from bottom to top), whereas android coordinates are flipped (`Y` increases from top to bottom). How do I convert matrices (`scale, translation, rotation`) to account for this difference?

Answer (score 0):

Get height android screen (or View you will draw your graph) and substract the Y-Coordinate from Windows

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int androidHeight = size.y;  //f.e. 720px 

newYValue = androidHeight - windowsYPosition    //f.e. 620px = 720px - 100px
```

Answer (score -1):

scale the Matrix by: 1, -1, you should probably use Matrix.preScale

Comment: I'm not using android matrix, but opengl matrix

Comment: @AngryChicken: Then simply multiply it with a (1, -1, 1, 1) scaling matrix.